# Responsively apply CSS class

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I'm trying to use something like the boostrap framework to selectively choose which css class to apply to a given element, based on the window size.

For example, in bootstrap, is there a way to choose which class to apply based on which of the `xs`, `sm`, `md` and `lg` divisions the browser falls under?

Is there any easy way to do this? Do I need to use javascript? Should I look towards something other than bootstrap?

Answer (score 6):

It sounds like you need a [media query](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries).

They will allow you to selectively apply styling depending on the window size.

For example:

```
@media all and (max-width: 1000px) {
  .element {
     color: blue;
  }
}
```

The above would apply a color of blue to the text of any html tag which has a class of `element` ONLY when the screen size width is below `1000px`.

Answer (score 0):

you can use css media queries or use javascript like

```
   $(document).ready(function() {

    var hei = $(window).height();
    var wid = $(window).width();
    if (hei <= 640 || wid <= 360) {
      $('element').css('property','value');
    }
    });
```